# CS26451: warning in Visual Studio. How do I resolve it?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pointers, overflow

Error:

> Using operator '*' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result into a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '*' to avoid overflow.

I have declared an array to use as shown. Here `Criterias` and `Decision_makers` are two variables declared as `unsigned short int`.

```cpp
long double* Decision_Matrix = new long double[Criterias * Decision_makers];
```

Then I use the array as shown below:

```
for (i = 0; i < Criterias; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < Decision_makers; j++)
    {
        *(Decision_Matrix + (i * Decision_makers) + j) = values;
        indata >> values;
    }
}
```

So, how do I resolve this error? It is showing a warning in Visual Studio.

Comment: Which statement is the error complaining about? What are `i` and `j` declared as exactly? On the assignment of `values` to the array, is there a reason why you are using pointer arithmetic instead of array notation? Do you still get the error if you use `Decision_Matrix[i * (Decision_makers) + j] = values;` instead?

Comment: The Error is about long double* Decision_Matrix=new long double[Criterias*Decision_makers].i and j have been declared as short int

Comment: although `operator*` will promote the `short` values to `int`, I see no way for that particular statement to produce that error, since there is no 8-byte value being used. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the help. I used Decision_Matrix[i*Decision_makers+j] as you suggested and the error was resolved